# Monero block explorer, xmrblocks, build failing

Tags: block-explorer

I am trying to build the onion Monero blockchain explorer. The build got through to 100% but then fails:

```
Scanning dependencies of target xmrblocks
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xmrblocks.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable xmrblocks
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/xmrblocks.dir/build.make:133: recipe for target 'xmrblocks' failed
make[2]: *** [xmrblocks] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:69: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xmrblocks.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmrblocks.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error, at the library linking phase, is stating it cannot find `libcurl`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
```

Install that and do a rebuild.

I would also double check you have any other dependencies installed before rebuilding.

To quote the [README](https://github.com/moneroexamples/onion-monero-blockchain-explorer/blob/master/README.md#compilation-on-ubuntu-16041804) section on how to build:

```
# first install monero dependecines
sudo apt update

sudo apt install git build-essential cmake libboost-all-dev miniupnpc libunbound-dev graphviz doxygen libunwind8-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libgtest-dev libreadline-dev libzmq3-dev libsodium-dev libhidapi-dev libhidapi-libusb0
```